# Lag function does not accept floating point values using postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, window

I'm trying to select a double precision (floating) value from a previous line of a table in PostgreSQL, but the lag() function is only working if the chosen column is an integer:

This code gives the error:

> "ERROR:  function lag(double precision, integer, integer) does not exist"

```
select id_client, date, value, lag(value, 1, 0) over (order by date)
```

This code works fine but i loose the decimals :

```
select id_client, date, value, lag(cast(value as int), 1, 0) over (order by date)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your default in lag function must be of the same type as main value:

`lag(value, 1, 0::double precision)` then it works

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

> select id_client, date, value, lag(value) over (order by date)